# Count a column in firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

How can I count a column just like we do in SQL queries? I want to count a specific phone number appearing in the table, in firebase realtime database.

I want to write a query in firebase realtime that retrieves this output like when using a SQL query like this:

```
select count (number) 
from users 
where number like 1234567890;
```

Comment: Hello, what did you try?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also respond using @AlexMamo